# Consuming files from external network at scale in Azure data pipeline

Tags: architecture, analytics, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

What is the best way to consume files from an external network at a scale? The goal here is to build data pipeline in Azure using Data Factory, ADLS and Databricks which can scale for almost real time consumption for analytics purpose.

Comment: I recommend you look for the Microsoft reference architecture diagrams for building a Modern Data Warehouse. This question is too generic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, you could use Databricks Notebook Activity in ADF pipeline:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook

Then you could configure min workers and max workers in databricks cluster.Please see [How autoscaling behaviors](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#how-autoscaling-behaves):

[image]